# Best way on Java to perform a basic operation with Long

Tags: java, optimization, mathematical-optimization

I have a Long number of 10 digits and I want to now the best way to implement this check. I'll explain it with an example:

If we have the number 3456789123:

```
3 will be multiplied by 10.
4 will be multiplied by 9.
5 will be multiplied by 8.
6 will be multiplied by 7.
...
2 will be multiplied by 2.
The last 3 will be multiplied by 1.
```

Therefore, the result of this operation will be returned:

```
(3*10) + (4*9) + ... + (2*2) + (1*1)
```

That is quite simple in a straightforward way, creating and array and multiplying, but I am trying to find the best solution.

Any hint?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the question, can you provide an example or explain the question more formally?

Comment: what weights? units,tens,hundreds?

Comment: You mean a linear combination?

Comment: I updated the question, I wasn't being very clear, sorry guys

Comment: Voting to reopen, clarification made the question much clearer. No idea why it was closed half an hour after edit that clarified the question was made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this might help you

```
long weight=1;
long finalSum=0;
while(number>0){
    long a=number%10;
    finalSum+=(a*weight);
    weight++;
    number/=10;
}
if((finalSum%11)==10){
    System.out.println("Final sum when divided by 11 gives remainder 10");
}
```

Comment: Please look at the Update

Answer (score 3):

```
       for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 

           long curr = x % 10  * (i+1);
           x = x / 10;
           System.out.println(curr);
           //do something with curr   
       }
```

Just repeatidly divide by 10 and take the rightest digit, and multiply it with an iterator of the current weight.

Comment: in case of 11 digits?

Comment: @Vihar It works for any number with less than 19 digits. By using a `BigInteger` it works for even bigger numbers as well. If you are referring that the number of digits is unknown apriori (which is not the case here) - it is fairly easy to find that out, using `Math.log10(.)`, for example.

Comment: yes sure,was just concerned for the amount of times for-loop runs which looks bit like hard-coding,never mind all is well

Comment: Please look at the Update

Comment: @stackpepe What are you struggling with? After applying the above, dividing by 11 and taking mod should be fairly easy, don't you think?